# How to set an owner and access mode for Nginx unix socket?

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx with `listen unix:/tmp/foo.sock;`.

Unfortunately, that socket is owned by root and world-writable/readable:

`srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Apr 11 00:37 /tmp/foo.sock`

While I'd like it to be owned by nginx user (`www-data` for example) and have mode `srw-rw----`.

I didn't find anything related [in nginx docs](http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen). And Google only tells me about backend sockets like for php-fpm.

Comment: Probably, I can put the socket in some private directory.

Comment: What will connect to the socket?

Comment: A front-end :-) In this case nginx is a back-end, and I don't want it listens TCP accepting any connection from any local user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days I put nginx socket into a "private" directory. Thus the socket is available to nginx itself and users belonging to nginx group.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an object on the file system I'd use standard file system tools. I'm not certain this will work, but it's at least worth a try. You should decide on file permissions, this is just an example - owner and group full read/write access seems sensible, not sure if it needs execute too which would be 770.

```
chown nginx:www-data /tmp/foo.sock
chmod 660 /tmp/foo.sock
```

Backups are your friend when you're trying something new.